# how to use git cherry pick to handle folder changes between different branches for the newly created file

Tags: git

We recently have a code structure change between two branches, namely, A and B. So when I try to cherry pick a change from B backward to A,

```
git cherry-pick commit-hash
```

if the files are previously existing, the changes are merged correctly (it seems git can track the previous-existing file for their folder change). However, I noticed there are two newly created files in B was merged into A with the new path (being auto created) rather than the old path. Is there any elegant way we can handle this?

Comment: What do you mean by elegant?

Comment: I mean anyway industry usually takes? For instance, NOT manually apply changes and re-check at branch A.

Comment: Are you aware when you cherry pick, you’re not cherry picking a change?

Comment: not cherry pick a change? could you give a little more explanation? Moreover, if you were me, what will you do?

Comment: There’s not really an easy one line solution for this. The commit you’re picking has file A in location X, so that’s where git puts it. If there are a lot of commits to be picked, pick them and then move the file.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, `git cherry-pick commit` is implemented as a three-way merge, with:

- the merge base set to the parent of the commit identified by *`commit`*;
- the current commit set to the current commit, as always;
- the other commit set to *`commit`*.

This merging action, or as I like to call it, "merge as a verb", proceeds as usual:

- run `git diff --find-renames base HEAD`, to find out what *we* changed
- run `git diff --find-renames base other`, to find out what *they* changed
- combine the two sets of changes, applying the combined changes to *`base`*

If this succeeds, Git makes a new ordinary (non-merge) commit as usual.  If it fails, Git stops with a merge conflict, leaving commit *`other`* identified by `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` instead of by `MERGE_HEAD`, so that your eventual final commit—assuming you choose to commit—makes an ordinary (non-merge) commit.

It's the `--find-renames` step that finds, or fails to find, renames.  It does so in the usual way.  For example, when comparing *`base`* to `HEAD`, if there exist files in *`base`* that do not exist in `HEAD` under the *same* names, Git will compare all unmatched *`base`* files to all unmatched `HEAD` files, to see which such files have similar content.  The two files with the *most* similar content will be paired up, provided the computed similiarity index meets or exceeds the minimum requred similarity index, as chosen by `-X find-renames=value`.  If there is no such `-X` argument the value defaults to 50 (i.e., 50% similar).

> So when I try to cherry pick a change from B backward to A,
>
> ```
> git cherry-pick commit-hash
> ```

Let's finish out that thought.  When you try to cherry pick that particular commit, Git finds that commit's parent, selects that as the merge base, and runs the above `git diff` command.  `HEAD` is set to the *name* `A`, so that the current commit is the tip commit of branch `A`, whatever that hash ID is.  Git therefore runs the equivalent `git diff --find-renames hash A`.  Do this yourself, with `--name-status` if you like (to get just file names and status-es including renames), and you will see which files Git has paired up between `hash` and `HEAD`.  If you read the previous paragraph, you already know what algorithm Git is using to do this pairing-up: it looks for *sufficiently similar* files that are not otherwise already paired.

If there can never be any such files, Git will not find any such files.  In that case it's up to you to adjust any file names if/as needed.